Calculate VIs in GEE over an image
In my study area shown in red line, I calculated an image of canopy height in GEE.  I want to calculate NDVI, EVI, and other vegetation indices over this image. I know how to calculate the VIs in GEE using Sentinel-2, however, I do not want to calculate over the whole study area. I want to set the canopy height map as an input. 
This is the GEE link

You just need to calculate VIs as usual and then add .updateMask(canopy_threshold) which you already used in your code when you clipped the canopy height map!
ee.Image.updateMask from the doc page here

Updates an image's mask at all positions where the existing mask is not zero. The output image retains the metadata and footprint of the input image.

Here is an example of what you need to add
var SentinelComposite = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterBounds(Border)
.filterDate('2020-02-01', '2020-04-01')
.mean();
var NDVI = SentinelComposite.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
var clippedNDVI = NDVI.updateMask(canopy_threshold).clip(Border)
Map.addLayer(clippedNDVI)


Thanks! I just needed to add the line 'var clippedNDVI = NDVI.updateMask(canopy)'. It did not even need the '.clip(Border)' !
